# How to read a tiff file in php?

Tags: php, image, gd, tiff

I know in the past the php Image processing and GD library has not supported reading a tiff file like imagecreatefrombmp and imagecreatefrompng. Just wondering if anyone knows has there been any recent updates/workarounds to reading a tiff into memory in a similar way (imagecreatefromtif) without using another library?

Thanks.

Comment: Your PHP might have various [Image Processing and Generation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/refs.utilspec.image.php) options build in. _Gmagick_ and _ImageMagick_ support TIFF files.